# Visual Basic Copy directory

Tags: .net, vb.net

When I tried copying a directory into another one it only copied the directory files I used this code snippet

```
My.Computer.Filesystem.CopyDirectory(Path, Backup, True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copydirectory.aspx)

make sure your Paths (first and second parameters that you pass) do NOT end with a "\".

Comment: Could not complete operation on some files and directories. See the Data property of the exception for more details.

Comment: Did you pass the third parameter (True)? You are probably running into an issue where a file(s) or a folder(s) exists already at the destination. If you aren't bothered about losing the destination directory (if it exists before copy), just do a delete before you do a copy using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory

Comment: I didn't do the third param I'll it